# Добавление в ListBox StackPanel'ов программно

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть приложение, которое генерирует текстовые значения. Есть ListBox, в который эти значения нужно выводить, но не только значения, но еще и определенный значек, им соответствующий, который должен помещаться слева от них. Вот пример того, что должно добавляться в ListBox:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Source="Examplesource.jpeg"/>
    <Label Content="Сгенерированный текст" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Как это сделать программно?

---

P.S Если кто-либо подскажет более удобный способ сделать это, то буду не против.

Comment: Используйте ItemTemplate и DataTemplate у ListBox для формирования разметки элементов. Шаблоны позволяют настроить практически любой вид для содержимого.

Comment: @AlexKrass Так, все почитал, все стало ясно, теперь сам, думаю, разберусь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте ItemTemplate и DataTemplate у ListBox для формирования разметки элементов. Шаблоны позволяют настроить практически любой вид для содержимого.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding КоллекцияЭлементов}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Examplesource.jpeg"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding СвойствоСгенерированногоТекста}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```